# MeteorJS setting a different mongodb url to run locally on windows

Tags: meteor

I am trying to run my mlab mongoDB locally on my computer from MeteorJS, so that when my Meteor code runs and gets put on localhost:3000, I look into the mLab mongoDB collections rather than local collections. I try to set the new mongo url like this on the command prompt:

```
set MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:password@stuff.mlab.com:11903/thing
```

After doing this and running meteor, however, I don't appear to access the mlab collections. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Run meteor with following command:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://DB_USER:PASSWORD@MLAB_URL:PORT/DB_NAME meteor
```

Answer (score 0):

when i run locally i use this.

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:password@stuff.mlab.com:11903/thing
```

it works for me. hope it will work for you also.